# html5 - figure element position importance

Tags: html, seo, figure

I am an advanced developer stuck with a simple question.
Is the position of a `<figure>` element on a webpage Important or not?
And what are some good use-cases of the figure element?

Generally, they say a `<figure>` element is used for photos, codeblock, diagrams, etc.
While the content of the `<figure>` element is related to the main flow, its position is independent of the main flow, and if removed it should not affect the flow of the document.

According to these articles from [Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/creative-professional/whats-difference-image-figure-tags-html5)
Use `<figure>` if the content is essential, but it's exact position on the page is important.

When I look at the article from [html.com](https://html.com/tags/figure/) 
the `<figure>` is for content directly related to the main content, while `<aside>` is for “tangentially related” content.

So a `<figure>` element contains self-contained content (content with meaning on itself). It can be removed and would not affect an article for example. And is only used for content directly related to the main content.

Please explain me why and when I should wrap my `<img>` inside a `<figure>` when a `<figcaption>` isn't needed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: I am not allowed to add SEO as category but I understand it is maybe more and purely SEO question. I just think there isn't a clear answer out there for starting developers who are learning Html5. When and where should they use the figure element. Without even thinking about SEO improvements. (I'll move my question to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)